# Forecasting using functional data analysis with parametric models for the functions

Tags: forecasting, functional-data-analysis

I have collected data at regularly spaced time intervals, and at each time, the observed data is commonly fit by a simple parametric functional form involving several parameters.

A naive approach to forecasting would be to treat each parameter as a univariate time series and use some forecasting method, like ARIMA, to forecast each of the parameters at some future time. Together, the forecast parameters would create the functional forecast at that time. I assume that potential correlations between the time series would make this problematic. Is that true? Is there a way to determine if it's actually not that big of a problem?

Otherwise, I guess you could use a multivariate time series forecasting approach, like VAR, although I am less familiar with those. Would such an approach be reasonable? What are some issues that would arise with forecasting in this way?

Is there a reference about this particular approach to forecasting and how it may be implemented?

Comment: [Forecasting of density function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/62826/1352) is not a duplicate (it asks for examples, not algorithms), but it might be useful. Unfortunately, there is not a lot of academic work on functional data forecasting. The [Hyndman & Shang (2009)](http://doi.org/10.1016/j.jkss.2009.06.002) paper I referred to at this other thread is the only such paper I am aware of. Searching [the agenda of the upcoming International Symposium on Forecasting](https://whova.com/portal/webapp/iwdu_202206/Agenda) for "functional" yields a few hits. Consider contacting the presenters?

Comment: what you describes sounds like a variation of state space modeling. you essentially posit that the observed data is a representation of some unobserved state variables. so your space of x's, observed, are a transformation with noise x=f(s)+e of unobserved state s. you try to estimate s, then forecast $\hat s$ and transform back to $\hat x$. there are many examples of this approach in different fields.

Comment: The first paper on this was [Hyndman & Ullah (CSDA, 2007)](http://doi.org/10.1016/j.csda.2006.07.028). Citations of that paper, including the one Stephan mentions, may also be useful.